# Dynamic array crashed for more than 8 elements

Tags: c++, c, arrays, dynamic, crash

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void arrayin(int x[], int n);
void arrayout(int x[], int n);
main()
{
    int n, x[n];
    cout << "Please enter the number of elements in the array: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Please enter the elements: " << endl;
    arrayin(x,n);
    cout << "Array is of " << n << " elements."<< endl;
    cout << "Elements are as follow :" << endl;
    arrayout(x,n); 
}
void arrayin(int x[],int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    {
        cin >> x[i];
    }
}   
void arrayout(int x[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << x[i] << "\t";
    }
}
```

I'm new to programming.
It crashes for more than 8 elements, if n > 8 crashes.. but for n<8 works fine..
Dont know why!

Comment: `int n`, `x[n];` ---> undefined behavior

Comment: I don't know, C++ supports VLA? I thought it was more of a C thing, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Are you compiling it as C++? (Not that that really matters since you declare `x[n]` before you know `n`). Variable length arrays are a `C` thing - in C++ I'd use a `vector`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh It's a GCC extension

Comment: C and C++ are quite different with respect to arrays. You should decide which one you have before asking here. From the view of it you are trying to use C concepts within C++. Don't do that, you'll never know what you get.

Comment: @StoryTeller So, to be clear, no C++ standard has it included, right? Atleast one C standard has the VLA as mandate.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Correct. C++ has no standard support for VLA. IIRC there *was* a proposal for a restricted form of VLA pointers, but it wasn't voted in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your array after taking input for n.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void arrayin(int x[], int n);
void arrayout(int x[], int n);
main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Please enter the number of elements in the array: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int x[n];
    cout << "Please enter the elements: " << endl;
    arrayin(x,n);
    cout << "Array is of " << n << " elements."<< endl;
    cout << "Elements are as follow :" << endl;
    arrayout(x,n);
}
void arrayin(int x[],int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    {
        cin >> x[i];
    }
}
void arrayout(int x[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << x[i] << "\t";
    }
}
```

This code works. The problem is when you declare array with no value for n the array will be initialized with whatever is on stack from past. Variable length arrays require the value. So declare the array later.

Someone downvoted without any reason.

Edit: Variable length arrays are not part of ISO C++. To write standard compliant C++ code you should use `-pedantic` flag with g++ or clang.

You have two simple choice. Either use std::array for fixed length arrays or std::vector for dynamic arrays.

Comment: Or.. use `std::vector<int>`

Comment: I downvoted WITH a reason.. your question, before editing,  consisted of "Declare your array after taking input for n.". this is not a real answer, it is a comment. After your edit I will withdraw my downvote. But IMO this answer is not useful since you did not mentioned about the nonstandard extensions. or even a real C++ solution

Comment: That is okay. There is no need to strain your voicebox. A programmer is supposed to use compiler well. The answer should also contain that for g++ one should use -pedantic -Wall for seeing this.

Comment: Yeah calm down @HumamHelfawi, you sound pretty stressed.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the problem:

```
 int n, x[n]; // It is undefined behaviour
 cout << "Please enter the number of elements in the array: " << endl;
 cin >> n;
```

The correct way is (on your compiler with the variable-size-array extension):

```
 int n;
 cout << "Please enter the number of elements in the array: " << endl;
 cin >> n;
 int x[n];
```

The correct way using C++ is to use `std::vector` instead:

```
 int n;
 cout << "Please enter the number of elements in the array: " << endl;
 cin >> n;
 std::vector<int> x(n);
```

and you have to make some other changes to adapt `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
int n, x[n];  // <-- n is not yet initialized
cout << "Please enter the number of elements in the array: " << endl;
cin >> n;
cout << "Please enter the elements: " << endl;
arrayin(x,n);
```

You need this:

```
int n;
cout << "Please enter the number of elements in the array: " << endl;
cin >> n;
int x[n];   // << now n has been initialized
cout << "Please enter the elements: " << endl;
arrayin(x,n);
```

BTW: VLA (or dynamic arrays as you call them) are non standard in C++, but gcc (and possibily clang) has them as extension.

Answer (score 2):

`int n, x[n];` is the problem

You are declaring `n` that will have an indeterminate value. With this value you are declaring an array that will have an indeterminate size.

You are using C++, so use `new` keyword to create your array, after user input:

```
cout << "Please enter the number of elements in the array: " << endl;
cin >> n;
int *x = new int[n];
// your stuff
delete x;
```